# I am trying to build react native app and I get this error: react native version mismatch expo

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CVtb.png)

react native version mismatch expo.

```
Javascript version : 0.60.5
Native Version: 0.59.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you running another app before trying to build this app?

We ran into this problem recently and it was because we have multiple apps, and one of them is on a different version of RN.

Our fix was to kill the packager/metro bundler and re-run to get the error to go away.

You could also update your apps to all run the same version of RN, but beware doing so, because you won't get this error when switching between apps while using the packager, but things won't work correctly either. When you switch between apps while developing you must kill the packager before running the next app.